# Chrome Extension: Huge list of cities for users to select

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

This is my first time creating a Chrome Extension and I'm also pretty new to JavaScript, so I hope this question is well structured!

In my Chrome Extension, I have a problem where I want the users to select a city (international, not just US) but the list is huge (200,000+). I did a bit of research, but being new to JavaScript/Chrome I wasn't sure which to go with.

A 200,000 item dropdown might kill the browser. Someone also suggested going with a textfield with autocomplete. However, the text/JSON file is almost 20 mb, so I'm not quite sure if that'll work or if that'll be the best solution.

What is the best approach to solve this problem? **Where users have to choose their city but within a huge (200k item plu) list?**

Thanks!

**Edit:**
With some of the suggestions below, would sorting first by country, then finding the cities within a country be better? I just tested how many cities in the US are in the JSON, and it's still 20k. Probably not the best, I'll keep looking hmm.

Comment: I would let them pick their state or zip code, then you can display the possible cities based on their state or zip code.

Comment: Even if 200,000+ cities in a drop down list doesn't kill the browser it's likely to kill any usability in your application. Whatever you do,  __don't__ do this!

Comment: I would distribute an SQLite DB with your extension, and build an autocompleter to query that database and display relevant results as people start to type a city.

Comment: Question is probably too broad, or even off-topic here (it's, in large part, a [ux.se] question)

Comment: too many ways to do this. focus your question on a couple alternatives after doing more research.

Comment: I would definitely try having the user select a country, then show another dropdown with regions/provinces (if applicable), then another with cities.